# YouTube animantions

Tags: android, animation, youtube

I would like to play video in my app and have animations like YouTube app has -- by swiping view from fullscreen mode view resize to small window in some corner.

I think I can do that if my video would be played in the same layout/ Does we have others options? I mean can I play my video in different activity or fragment in fullscreen mode and by swipe close this and show small window in previous activity (with animation)

Comment: i have this problem now, did you get the answer?

Comment: I implemented my own solution:
-  You have a lyaout for a full screen
-  You have a layout for a minimized screen
-  You have s stub which you animate 
There is an issue with ViewoView animation so you need a placeholder -- you animate it and just show a VieoView at the end of the animation

Comment: How you have animate that